# Вебсокеты показывают два клиента, хотя по факту 1

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
const initWebSocket = (webSocketServer) => {
  wss = webSocketServer

  const messageChangeStream = mongoose.connection.db
    .collection('messages')
    .watch()

  messageChangeStream.on('change', (change) => {
    if (change.operationType === 'insert') {
      const newMessage = change.fullDocument

      wss.clients.forEach((client) => {
        console.log('Client Info:', client._socket.remoteAddress)

        if (client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
          client.send(
            JSON.stringify({
              processing: 'add',
              data: newMessage,
            })
          )
        }
      })
    }
  })
}

Client Info: ::ffff:127.0.0.1
Client Info: ::1
```

Почему в wss сидит два соединения, хотя по факту я один клиент присоединил, и как этого избежать можно?

Comment: Первый соединение `http|s`, а потом идет открытие протокола `ws|s`, что-то такое.. `Web Socket Protocol Handshake Upgrade: WebSocket Connection: Upgrade`

Comment: @Jour а как итерироваться только по протоколу ws|s? я просто с серверной частью не особо(

Comment: никак) почитайте что-то вроде https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/171066/ ... ваш код вообще странноват) что вы пытаетесь сделать? мб оно .. https://www.mongodb.com/developer/languages/javascript/nodejs-change-streams-triggers/

Comment: @Jour ну мне приходит сообщение на вебсокет, я его обрабатываю и хочу всем пользователям кто на него подписан вернуть

Comment: нужно сделать сервер, что принимает соединение с клиентом, авторизирует* его и апгрейдит конект в вебсокет) после чего общается клиент с сервером по протоколу вебсокет и все хорошо) шли куда хочешь и кому надо...